# custom vertical image list view with ajax new image request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to implement custom control - image list which will be retrive new portion of images each time when user see all current image.

I decide to use custom jquery event which fired when bottom of the page reached. Is it a good enough approach for that matter? Will it some problems during multiple event could be fired?

Also, is such plugin already exist? Thanks.

Comment: don't hesitate to vote for the answer if you are satisfied with it ;)

Comment: I make an up vote for you. But your answer is a little bit different then what I asking for, so for now I can't marked it like question right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle multiple event firing anyway since you don't know how long it will take for loading the images. This means you keep track of images that are currently loading, which is not so complex.

I suggest you fire the event before the end of the page is reach for unlimited scrolling effect.

Comment: Yes, I have an 100px limit before page end. But I think that multiple event occurance could be a possible problem.

Comment: I believe you know beforehand the list of images you want to load, don't you? If so, maintain a `boolean` array of loaded images. Only load the images that have never been loaded before. If not, I believe you retrieve the new image name via Ajax, in which case, just double check it is not in the page yet before adding it to the DOM. The risk of loading too many images is not critical as long as it is not pictured twice, or is it?